# R: How to compute mean of every 10 lines of a variable

Tags: r

I have some datasets that were collected by every 1 min, but I have to replace the data by mean of 10 mins data. So I have this R code.

```
for(k in 1:(length(temp[,1])/10)){
  temp2[k,1]<-temp[1,1]
  temp2[k,2]<-temp[k*10,2]
  temp2[k,3]<-mean(na.omit(as.numeric(temp[((k-1)*10+1):k*10,3])))
}
```

However, the efficiency of this code is tooooo low.
And one more question. Because of some missing data, the time variable is not always continuous. And I have to compute data of every true 10 mins (that is 2014-01-01 00:00 to 2014-01-01 00:10, for example), no matter how many obs in this 10 mins. So the loop goes to

```
  tmp<-na.omit(temp[temp[,2]>(st+600*(k-1)) & temp[,2]<=(st+600*k),])
  temp2[k,1]<-tmp[1,1]
  temp2[k,2]<-st+600*k
  temp2[k,3]<-mean(na.omit(as.numeric(tmp[,3])))
```

which cannot be bearable. And it cannot effectively handle case like "some months are missing".
So, how can I solve this in R, while the efficiency is not low.

Original data:

```
Time  Var1
2014-01-01 00:01  10
2014-01-01 00:02  12
2014-01-01 00:03  43

...
2014-01-01 00:10  52
```

desired output:

```
Time  Var1
2014-01-01 00:10  (mean of every 10 mins)
2014-01-01 00:20  (mean of every 10 mins)
...
```

Comment: Can you provide some data and the desired output?

Comment: You need to dump us a redacted subset of your data with `dput()`. Check out `zoo::rollmean()` fn and `tseries` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `xts` package, and specifically the `period.apply` function with `endpoints`

Assuming you can get your data as an xts object (in this case called `xt.data`, then the something like the following will work.

```
# example data
times <- seq(Sys.time()-50000,Sys.time(),by=60)
mydt <- data.frame(time = times[sample(seq_along(times),size=300)], test = runif(300)) 
xt.data <- as.xts(mydt[,2], order.by= mydt[['time']])

period.apply(xt.data, endpoints(xt.data,'minutes',10),mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `?cut.POSIXt`, `?seq.POSIXt` and `round.POSIXt`. The `cut` and `seq` functions allows the breaks to be set at `"10 min"` intervals but sadly the round function does not seem to have that nice feature. You might multiply by 10, round to the nearest "min" and divide by 10, but I haven't tried all this.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep in mind there's a POSIXlt format for time that makes manipulating each component trivial then it's relatively easy. What I've done here is read in the data with the POSIXct format (because you can't read in with POSIXlt), convert to POSIXlt, then just group by 10s of minutes, convert back, and do an aggregate. This should run pretty fast.

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'time, y
                          2014-01-01 00:01, 10
                          2014-01-01 00:02, 12
                          2014-01-01 00:22, 43', 
                          header = TRUE, sep = ',', colClasses = c('POSIXct', 'numeric'))
dat$time <- as.POSIXlt(dat$time)
dat$time[[2]] <- floor(dat$time[[2]] / 10) * 10
dat$time <- as.POSIXct(dat$time)
aggregate(y ~ time, data = dat, mean)
```

As an aside, you said replace by every 10 minutes, not aggregate. In that case the aggregate lines would become:

```
y$time <- ave(y, time)
```

And, if you wanted to keep the original times and all other data intact but just replace by the means across 10min you could replace everything after `read.table` with:

```
dat$time <- as.POSIXlt(dat$time)
g <- floor(dat$time[[2]] / 10) * 10
dat$y <- ave(y, g)
```